# Access home page of a sharepoint online site from code

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, azure-ad, oauth, postman

I have a sharepoint site hosted at:

https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com, which has a subsite named abc

when I type in https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/abc in the browser, it redirects to the welcome page of the subsite automatically, which is https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/abc/Pages/Home.aspx.

But when I try to access this subsite using postman, it does not redirects to the welcome page by itself, even if I try to access the welcome page like this:
https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/abc/Pages/Home.aspx
by using the oauth2 token, it gives error 401 unauthorized.

How to access the home page of a sharepoint subsite from postman and retrieve its HTML?

Answer (score 0):

The Url of the designated "default" or "home" page is stored in a property named `WelcomePage`.  To retrieve this value from a REST call, perform a GET `"<<subsiteurlhere>>/_api/web/rootfolder?$select=welcomepage"`.  Since it is a GET request, you can even test this in the browser, for example:

```
https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/abc/subweb1/_api/web/rootfolder?$select=welcomepage
```

Also note, that if you performed Oauth to get your token from the parent site, depending on how your permissions are configured, you may have to re-authenticate to get a valid token for the subsite.

**Update from comments**:

Hit the REST endpoint in browser tab like below and check if this works for you before using it in postman:

[image]

Comment: Tried it, like this https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/abc/pages/_api/web/rootfolder?$select=welcomepage, but it gives me error this error: {"error_description":"Invalid issuer or signature."}. Using oauth2 Password credentials flow .

Comment: "/pages" is not part of your web URL

Comment: shall it be literally used like this: https://xxx.sharepoint.com/abc/subweb1/_api/web/rootfolder?$select=welcomepage

Comment: Also, how to handle error 401 . It shows me this in the response headers: x-ms-diagnostics →3000006;reason="Token contains invalid signature.";category="invalid_client"

Comment: The part that comes before the "_api" should only include the path to your site or subsite.  Library or lists should not be in the base path.  So if your site is https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/abc, and the "abc" site has a subsite named subweb1, then the API call would be `https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/abc/subweb1/_api/web/rootfolder?$select=welcomepage`.  Of course, you want to use real address of your site and subsite.

Comment: How are you getting your oauth token that you are passing?

Comment: If you open your site in the browser, then use this API URL in the browser, it should work under your security context.  If it does not, then you have your URL wrong.

Comment: I am getting the oauth2 token in postman, by using the Password credentials flow with the client id, client secret, username and user password. Scope is Sites.Read.All. The client id, client secret here are generated by registering an app in Azure AD. Because our organisation uses Azure AD for authentication, so we registered one app there and use its credentials to get the oauth2 token.

Comment: Since this is a simple GET, you should be able to just put the URL in your browser bar and get it like a webpage without messing with oauth.  Can you test it that way first?

Comment: Hit the REST endpoint in browser tab and check if this works for you before using it in postman: check the updated answer and attached image reference.

Comment: if I hit this url directly in browser without doing login into the sharepoint, which means without doing anything for oauth, I get this message:       <m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">
Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.
</m:message>
</m:error>

Comment: If you visit your site and login by just going to your site's url (e.g. `https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/abc/subweb1`), then change the url in that browser bar to hit the REST endpoint (e.g. `https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/abc/subweb1/_api/web/rootfolder?$select=welcomepage`), and you still get 'Access Denied' then you are formatting your URL incorrectly.

Comment: if I visit my site and login, and then try to browse this: https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/abc/_api/web/rootfolder?$select=welcomepage.     I get this response:

Comment: <id>https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/abc/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/abc/')</id>
<category term="SP.Folder" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
<link rel="edit" href="Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/abc/')" />
<title /><updated>2020-03-03T05:24:41Z</updated><author><name />
</author><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:WelcomePage>Pages/Home.aspx</d:WelcomePage>
</m:properties></content></entry>. Is it waht is expected?

Comment: Yes, without the ability to set the conten-type header, hitting a GET API through the browser will often return XML.  You can see in the response that it is giving you the relative path of your site's homepage in the `<d:WelcomePage>` element.

Comment: So, now we know we have the correct URL endpoint to execute the service call with the same URL.

Comment: so, how do I retrieve the html from this call, by setting content type header to - text/html? and how about the invalid client exception in postman. do I need to follow this guide - http://pratapreddypilaka.blogspot.com/2018/05/sharepoint-online-authentication-for.html and register one app in the sharepoint and use its credentials? or follow this guide - https://blog.mastykarz.nl/azure-ad-app-only-access-token-using-certificate-dotnet-core/

Comment: Is this a classic wiki or publishing page, or is this a "modern" page.

Comment: How to identify the type of page? if I try to find Home.aspx in the site, I find it under Site contents->Site pages ->Home.aspx